# aws comprehend with aws lambda in node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-comprehend

https://[aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-comprehend-for-sentiment-analysis/](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-and-amazon-comprehend-for-sentiment-analysis/)

From the post i was able to use **comprehend** to detect sentiment analysis but it was in python

can somebody please provide the same code in node.js

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of examples in the docs for the JavaScript SDK, which you can find here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Comprehend.html